# jQuery .off() not removing event

Tags: javascript, jquery

The setup I have makes an ajax request to a php script to grab some images from the server and display them. During the ajax request, I enable some additional controls. I have two modes for the images, one that brings up a larger version of the image, and one that lets me sort them.

I implemented a checkbox so that I can swap between the two modes. Whenever I click search and invoke the ajax request, the images correspond to the mode that the checkbox had when they were created.

What I want to do is make it so clicking the checkbox allows me to swap the mode without having to search again.

```
$.ajax({
    url: './search.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#images").html(data);  
        enableControls();
    },
```

This is the snippet of the ajax request where I receive the images, add them to my page, and enable the controls.

```
$('#sortable').change(function() {
    enableControls();
});
```

This is the snippet where I allow my checkbox to change the state of the controls.

```
function enableControls() {
    $('.img-responsive').off();
    if($('#sortable').is(":checked")) {
        $('.img-responsive').on('dblclick', sortableDoubleClick);
    }
    else {
        $('.img-responsive').on('dblclick', imgDoubleClick);
    }
}
```

This is a snippet where I enable the double click behaviour. Double clicking while it's in sort mode will make that image go to the front (top left) of the rows/columns of images. Double clicking while it's in the non-sort mode will bring up a larger version of the image.

The img-responsive class is a class all the images returned from the search have, and is how I reference them as a group.

Unfortunately, the line

```
$('.img-responsive').off();
```

does not work the way I want it to. I want it to completely disable existing controls so I can set whatever new ones I want. It does not do that. What happens right now is that I get both double click controls available.

So let's say I search in non-sort mode and then click my checkbox to put it in sort mode. When I double click on an image, it opens up the larger version of it AND moves it to the top left.

How can I fix this? I assume the way I am invoking .off() is incorrect, but as far as I understand, .off() should remove all the event handlers for the selector, so why is it the case that I still retain the original event handler?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving my problem. In the portion of the code:

```
$('.img-responsive').on('dblclick', imgDoubleClick);
```

There was some additional code for touch controls:

```
$('.img-responsive').each(doubletapCover);
```

For some reason, even though that code path never occurred, it seemed to invoke that code. I made a change so it's not ever called and it fixes my problem.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.